# C# - Removing special character camel style word

Tags: c#, regex

I am splitting words from camel style string.Example

```
    string str = "winAgainWinBest";
    string r = @"(?=[A-Z])";
    var splitted = Regex.Split(str, r);
```

I get the result

```
win
Again
Win
Best
```

When the string is mixed with special characters how will i remove it and get the words?

I mean  `string str = "win++Again@@Win--Best\\";`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
var splitted = Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(str, @"\W+", ""), @"(?=[A-Z])");
```

`\W` is a shorthand for `[^\w]` (which equals: `[^0-9a-zA-Z_]`) and therefore matches any character except `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+[a-z]+)
```